# Why isn't subplots in matplotlib working?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.8

I have a python-script that is meant to test the functionality of matplotlib (among others). The script is **working in terminal and Python console**, but not in saved files executed from PyCharm (Linux) or Visual Studio Code (Windows). I do get the same error message for both environments about *subplots* missing, se screen dump:
[image]

The matplotlib code is copied from [matplotlibs website for example code](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_colors.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-bar-colors-py). What am I missing?

Comment: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Comment: shouldn't it be `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small difference between your code and the example code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # import in the example
import matplotlib as plt # your code
```

Just need to fix your import.

Comment: Thanks! And I'm also a little ashamed for missing that. I was so sure about my imports that I never even looked at it. :)